# How to change order in Ember.js model representation?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model `Module` which represents an array of objects, in JSON like:

```
modules": [{
    "id": "123456",
    "type": "video",
    "url": "http://some.where.com/video.mp4"
}, {
    "id": "123457",
    "type": "text",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..."
}]
```

I have a UI that allows user to arrange order of those objects, **how to tell Ember.js to change that order in model?** To be able to save date with different order.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably add a `position` field to the data and use that to determine the position.   Depending on your application, you might consider persisting the position to the db, however you can also have it as a field in your `ArrayController`.

[Here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html#property_sortAscending) is a link to the `SortableMixin`'s API in case you find that useful as well.